# switching to another Ubuntu flavour?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I switched to Ubuntu Studio (Xenial) from Windows 8.1, since I mostly only used open source tools. But, I'm finding it hard than the original Ubuntu, to install program, getting errors most of the time failing installations.

Is there a way, that I could switch to the original Ubuntu flavour, without altering any of my fies? Including the production applications that were included in Ubuntu Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't,

Each flavor of Ubuntu comes with a set of pre-installed applications, what I can suggest you to do is a fresh install.

You can get a backup from your personal files, and a list of all installed applications on your Ubuntu studio:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

Then after your installation, add these packages to your Ubuntu, you can also get a backup from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` to decrease your download size.